# Is my computer secure?

Tags: malware, antivirus, rootkit, rkhunter

I was using Rkhunter and this was displayed.

```
[ Rootkit Hunter version 1.4.2 ]
File updated: searched for 175 files, found 141
baymax@vostro:~$ sudo rkhunter -c --enable all --disable none --rwo
Warning: The following processes are using deleted files:
         Process: /sbin/upstart    PID: 935    File: /home/baymax/.cache/upstart/at-spi2-registryd.log.1
         Process: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/bamf/bamfdaemon    PID: 1079    File: /home/baymax/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/root
         Process: /usr/bin/unity-scope-loader    PID: 1970    File: /home/baymax/.cache/software-center/software-center-agent.db/record.DB
         Process: /usr/lib/firefox/firefox    PID: 2706    File: /var/tmp/etilqs_ZS8Z4Cd20kgd6uC
Warning: Process '/sbin/wpa_supplicant' (PID 755) is listening on the network.
Warning: Process '/sbin/dhclient' (PID 904) is listening on the network.
Warning: Suspicious file types found in /dev:
         /dev/shm/pulse-shm-3832399606: data
         /dev/shm/pulse-shm-3456808388: data
         /dev/shm/pulse-shm-315771165: data
         /dev/shm/pulse-shm-3931089998: data
         /dev/shm/pulse-shm-3100407829: data
         /dev/shm/pulse-shm-876765117: data
Warning: Hidden file found: /dev/.initramfs: symbolic link to `/run/initramfs'
```

I had opened firefox and some ads were displayed because i forgot to install adbockplus and well a while later firefox was freezing as well some other apps.

I have heard that malware  can now automatically execute despite enabling/disabling ads. Just want to make sure i am not infected in anyway.

Thank you.

Ref: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-rkhunter-to-guard-against-rootkits-on-an-ubuntu-vps

Commands copied and pasted into Terminal:

```
sudo rkhunter --propupd

sudo rkhunter -c --enable all --disable none --rwo
```

Comment: Ehm I don't think you have to be worried. So far I know ads can not compromise your system, as long your firefox/chrome stay up to date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your current `rkhunter` output, you're completely fine. All of that is perfectly normal for a network-connected and running system.